# Can SQLExpress 2005 and 2008 be installed on same machine without issue?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, installation

I would like to install SQLExpress2005 as an instance "SQLExpress"
and install SQLExpresss2008 as "SQLExpress2008" instance.

Is there any problem with doing this on the same machine?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you not want to just upgrade to SQL Server 2008 Express? You can set your databases that were made under 2005 to 2005 compatibility mode. (But other than that, you should be able to do this IIRC.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Long as you give them distinct names, there shouldn't be any problems. The binaries are stored in directories based on version, and you can (and should) point their filegroups at different locations. This should also apply to the Full versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can with the full version of SQL, but you need to do it by installing named instances. This could be an issue with SQL Express where it doesn't give you that option.

Comment: You can edit the Setup files to change the named instance from "SQLEXPRESS" to whatever you want. You just have to do it before starting setup.

Answer (score 0):

Works on my machine :) Just avoid instance conflicts. Have at most one default instance and the named instance(s) should be unique.